revertWith("Not Enough Tokens") Invalid Chai property: revertedWith
    it("Should fail if sender does not have enough tokens" , async function(){
        const initialOwnerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address); //  initially - 0 tokens addr1
        await expect(hardhatToken.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address , 1)).to.be.revertedWith("Not enough tokens");

        expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address).toString()).to.equal(initialOwnerBalance.toString());
    }) 

it gives this Error
Should fail if sender does not have enough tokens:
Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith
i also try rejectWith but that is also gives the same error
I am trying to to revert it when the error occurred in the smart contract
